# curl request for a resource that consumer MULTIPART_FORM_DATA

Tags: curl, jersey, glassfish, multipartform-data, multipart

How do I write a curl request to test a resource that accepts multipart form data?

```
   @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   void resourceA(Multipart multipartbody){
       log.info("resourceA");
       for (bodypart : multipartbody.getBodyParts()) {
           //process body part
       }
   }
```

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --form "data=@SamplePNGImage_1mbmb.png;type=image/png" <resourceUrl>
```

returns a 404 Not found, the log line `resourceA` is not logged.

Comment: Try not to set the content-type header. This should get added implicitly (with the required _boundary_) when you use form data parameters. It's possible an error on the server side causes the search for an error page that doesn't exist, hence the 404.

Comment: are you sure about the PUT? That's unusual for multipart formposts...